# How to show properly $ 10n^4 + 3n^3 -n \in O(n^4)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science, number-comparison

Given:
$$ 10n^4  + 3n^3  -n \in O(n^4)$$

So i do understand Big O and what it does. I am however not quite if my approach for the solution is correct, so anyone who could help me out or show me an alternative approach if mine is not correct would be awesome.
My solution:

$$  \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {f(x)}{n^4} \ = 10 => f(n) = \Theta(n^4)$$

so
$$ 10n^4  + 3n^3  -n \in O(n^4)$$

is not true.
Plotting both functions seem to show exactly what i found out:
[image]

Is that however correct?

Comment: $f(n)\in \Theta(g(n))\implies f(n)\in O(g(n))\land f(n)\in\Omega(g(n))$ !

Answer (score 2):

By definition
$10n^4+3n^3−n\in O(n^4)$ if and only if there exist $n_0$ and $M$ such that
$$|10n^4+3n^3−n|\leq M n^4 \quad \forall n\geq n_0.$$
Using triangular inequality and the fact that $n^4$ is larger or equal than $n^3$ and $n$ (if $n\geq 1$) yields
$$|10n^4+3n^3−n|\leq |10n^4|+|3n^3+|-n|=10n^4+3n^3+n\leq 10n^4+3n^4+n^4 = 14 n^4 \quad \forall n\geq 1$$
the definition is fulfilled with $M=14$ and $n_0=1$ and thus $10n^4+3n^3−n\in O(n^4)$.

Equivalently, since
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10n^4+3n^3−n}{n^4}=10  $, then $10n^4+3n^3−n\in O(n^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about what the big-O notation means.  Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(n)}{n^4} = 10,$$ we know that for sufficiently large $n$, $$\frac {f(n)}{n^4}<15\implies f(n)<15n^4\implies f(n)=O(n^4)$$

Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n^4}{f(n)}=1,$$ it is also true that $$n(n)=\Theta(n^4),$$ but this in no way invalidates the statement that $f(n)=O(n^4)$.  It is, in fact, a stronger statement.

I don't understand how you believe the graph contradicts this statement, but it cannot, since the statement is true.

**EDIT**

Any number greater than $10$ can be used in place of $15$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(n)}{n^4} = 10$ means that $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists N$ such that $n>N\implies \left\lvert \frac {f(n)}{n^4}-10\right\rvert <\varepsilon$.  If we take $\varepsilon =5$, we get $5<\frac{f(n)}{n^4}<15$.

Comment: thanks! Would you like to tell me where you did get the < 5 from?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $15$.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: thank you! So basically whenever i get lim→∞()4= i can automatically say that it is in O(n^4) and also in Ω(4). Likewise, for 0 and infinity i get either just O or $\Omega (n^4). Thanks for clarifying it! I understood it now!

Answer (score 1):

As Yves mentionned, $f(n) \in \Theta(n^4)$ implies that $f(n) \in O(n^4)$.

Big O notation matters only as $n \rightarrow + \infty$, that is why you are computing the limit of the function over $n^4$ only there.

You do not care that $f$ goes below $n^4$ for small values, what big O says is "for sufficiently large values of $n$, $f$ is lower than some $k n^4$ for some fixed $k$". You can check that $f$ is indeed smaller than $11n^4$ in the limit if you want to convince yourself.

Comment: so whenever i get $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(n)}{n^4} = c $ i can automatically say that it is in O(n^4) and also in  $\Omega(n^4) $. True?

Comment: Basically if this fraction doesn't go to infinity it means f doesn't grow faster than $n^4$ so f is in $O(n^4)$. As Saul said, to prove it is in $\Omega (n^4)$, you need the to have the inverse fraction not go to infinity. This is not be the case if the limit of $f(n)/(n^4)$ is $0$. The reason it works here is because the limit is non-null and constant, so the limit of the inverse is also constant.